# how can i block symbols like <>;()" in URL

Tags: javascript, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string, httpd.conf

how can i block symbols like **<>;()"** in URL but after DNS(www.xyz.com).
I am using **httpd** apache file and  **two location** blocks. One for **Root(/)** and other for **Location /login**.

i tried ---
Location />

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE  application/x-javascript application/javascript

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(<|>|%3C|%3E|;|\(|\)|%3A|%3B).*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/homepage.html [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(<|>|%3C|%3E).*   [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

/Location>
```

everything works except for query_string part.
If i pass any malicious content after question-mark then it is still redirecting to login or home page or desired page.

**For that i added following code -**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(<|>|%3C|%3E|;|\(|\)|%3A|%3B).*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

but now, login page is in-accessible. 
please help me write a simple code so the web-server block URL, if any of the special char comes after www.xyz.com/

Comment: I dont think JS can handle it and should be handled on server.

Comment: It is not safe to assume the user will be using utf8/ascii, if you are going to handle this you have to cover urlencoded strings, alternate character sets, Unicode astral planes.